# Specifying include path to boost to one place only in g++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, include-path

I am working on a code base that uses the boost libraries.  But, I recently ran into problems building the base on a new user's machine.  I was able to boil the problem to the following.  Here's how the build system looks like:

```
/root
    /SubModules_with_Makefiles_and_Code
    /thirdparty/boost
```

The submodule code will reference boost stuff like so (for example):

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
```

And the sub module make files will build such a code like so (for example):

```
g++ -c -o code.o code.cpp -I/root/thirdparty/boost
```

Our 3rd party boost library is version 1.37.  However, some modules have begun using later versions of boost.  This problem has been masked because the machines where these modules have been built contain boost 1.41 installed in /usr/include/boost.

The problem came to bear because the new user's machine did not have boost 1.41 installed in /usr/include.  Ideally, I would like g++ to look for boost in the third party directory and nowhere else.  This way, we can have tighter control of how the code base gets built.

-I<dir> places <dir> before the system includes during lookup, but system includes are still looked at and that is where later versions of boost can be installed depending on the machine.  I can suppress looking at the system includes, but that would be a real pain.

Is there anyway smart way to go about this, other than replacing:

```
#include <boost/something.hpp>
```

to

```
#include <thirdparty/boost/something.hpp>
```

?  If it helps, I am using gnu make 3.81 and g++ 4.4.5 on redhat linux.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'include path' command line option (-I). You can set where
it searches for included files. Documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if -I will help in this instance.  If a later  version of a SomeBoost.hpp is not found in -I/root/thirdparty, /usr/include will still be looked at for the SomeBoost.hpp.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at section 2.3 of the gcc manual: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

The compiler switch you are looking for would most probably be

```
-nostdinc
```

But better take a look yourself.

EDIT: oop, I just saw you DONT want to disable the default search path - in that case just use the -I switch:

> You can add to this list with the -Idir command line option. All the directories named by -I are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the timely response, but adding -I won't solve the problem.  (I don't think).   The problem is a developer could have a later version of boost installed in /usr/include.  So, -I only places directories to look at before standard directories like /usr/include, but it doesn't replace /usr/include.  So, if someone adds in #include <boost/SomeLaterVersion.hpp> to their code, the later version can still be picked up even if -I/root/thirdparty is added, because it SomeLaterVersion.hpp could be lurking in /usr/include, after /root/thirdparty is looked at.

Comment: Searching /usr/local/include AFTER the directories explicitly specified by -I shouldn't be a problem, as the first match will be used. You might want to check the order with the '-v' option to cpp. It should list the order in which directories are searched.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I don't see that behavior on my machine.  I agree if g++ find a header in /root/thirdparty/boost-1.37 it will use that first.  But if a header file is not in boost-1.37, but in a later boost version, it will look at /usr/include.  So for instance boost/heap/binomial_heap.hpp is in boost 1.49, so it will go looking for the file outside of /root/thirdparty/boost-1.37.

Comment: Sure it will search until the first match ist found. As /usr/include is the last directory searched I don't see the actual problem. If hasn't been found so far either the right path to the desired headers wasn't given in a -I switch or they aren't existent on the system at all, so there won't be any chance of (correctly) compiling anyway. To prevent the second case you probably just might check BOOST_VERSION against the version you are using and thwrow an #error if the versions don't match.

Comment: I guess the problem is if g++ looks outside the thirdparty directory, that gives less control of what is  being built.  if all developers have different versions of boost installed on their machines, then that could potentially mean different behaviors at build and even at run time.  I want to minimize this behavior as much as possible by limiting g++ to look only in the thirdparty directory and not outside of it for boost library.  We've already run into this problem a number of times using boost thread.  Anyways, I guess I'll need to think harder about what really needs to get done.  Thanks!